# How do I convert the following expression from POSIX to PCRE?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre, eregi

I wish there was a simple utility that would do this, as regular expressions scare me. I'd like to update the following to `preg_replace()` if anyone could explain to me how.

`eregi_replace('([a-zA-Z0-9_]{'.$min_char.','.$max_char.'})','', $password)`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As a general rule, as long as the POSIX regex isn't using any of the `[:WACKY:][:CHARACTER:][:CLASS:]` syntax, you can just add delimiters and have it work in PCRE without too much trouble.  [Here's the PCRE manual page on differences between it and POSIX](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to remember that. My only fear is knocking something off and not testing it enough to notice. Thankfully this is a fairly simple one, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be just

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{$min_char,$max_char})/

preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{'.$min_char.','.$max_char.'})/','', $password)
```

As far as I can see only the delimiter are missing.